# getting categoryid fo more than one shortname passed

Tags: postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
business
id  catid    subcatid
---------------------
10   {1}        {10,20} 
20   {2}        {30,40} 
30   {3}        {50,60,70}

cat_subcat
catid       shortname      parent_id    bid
--------------------------------------------
 1           A                           10
 2           B                           20 
 3           c                           30
 10          x                 1         10 
 20          y                 1         10
 30          z                 2         20
 40          w                 2         20
```

Both the tables have a relationship using id. The problem I am getting is outlined below. Here is my query currently:

```
 SELECT ARRAY[category_id]::int[]   from cat_subcat
     where  parentcategoryid IS not NULL and  shortname ilike ('x,y');
```

I want to get the `category_id` for an entered `shortname`, but my query is not giving the proper output. If I pass one `shortname` it will retrieve the `category_id`, but if I pass more than one `shortname` it will not display `category_id`. Please tell me how to get the `category_id` for more than one `shortname` passed.

Comment: It's unclear what you need exactly. You have `parentcategoryid` and `category_id` in your query, but not in your table definition. It's better to provide a proper table definition: what you get with `\d tbl` in psql. If you have a hard time describing what you need, add the expected result to clarify. And your version of Postgres, as always.

Answer (score 1):

To actually use pattern matching with `ILIKE`, you *cannot* use a simple [`IN` expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN). Instead, you need `ILIKE` [`ANY (...)` or `ALL (...)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ALL), depending on whether you want the tests ORed or ANDed:

Also, your `ARRAY` constructor will be applied to individual rows, which seems rather pointless. I assume you want this instead (educated guess):

```
SELECT array_agg(catid) AS cats
FROM   cat_subcat
WHERE  parent_id IS NOT NULL
AND    shortname ILIKE ANY ('{x,y}');
```

Well, as long as you don't use wildcards (`%`, `_`) for your pattern, you can translate this to:

```
AND    lower(shortname) IN ('x','y');
```

But that would be rather pointless, since Postgres internally converts this to:

```
AND    lower(shortname) = ANY ('{x,y}');
```

.. before evaluating.